# Create a pull event in yii

Tags: php, yii2

My problem is that I want to create an event in Yii where you don't have to push the function which is being called when an event is called. As you can see in the example method "sendMailToAdmin" is called specifically when the event is called. But we can not call this a proper event, as we are just calling a method in another method. I want to just raise an event and then a method can check if that event is called and then it can run itself. This will be a pull operation instead of the push operation. Is this possible using Yii event? Also, i don't want to use any socket programming to solve this.

For example - If I want to add user role in the `user_role` table when a user is created then, the `UserRole` model should be able to catch this event and create a new entry in user role table. Instead of attaching event using `on` in `init` of `MyUser` model

Here is my code

```
<?php
   namespace app\models;
   use Yii;
   /**
   * This is the model class for table "user".
   *
   * @property integer $id
   * @property string $name
   * @property string $email
   */
   class MyUser extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
      const EVENT_NEW_USER = 'new-user';
      public function init() {
         // first parameter is the name of the event and second is the handler.
         $this->on(self::EVENT_NEW_USER, [$this, 'sendMailToAdmin']);
      }
      /**
      * @inheritdoc
      */
      public static function tableName() {
         return 'user';
      }
      /**
      * @inheritdoc
      */
      public function rules() {
         return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
         ];
      }
      /**
      * @inheritdoc
      */
      public function attributeLabels() {
         return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
         ];
      }
      public function sendMailToAdmin($event) {
         echo 'mail sent to admin using the event';
      }
    }
    ?>

   public function actionTestEvent() {
   $model = new MyUser();
   $model->name = "John";
   $model->email = "john@gmail.com";
   if($model->save()) {
      $model->trigger(MyUser::EVENT_NEW_USER);
   }
   }
```

Comment: what i am unable to understand is why you are saying that your event binding is not correct? it IS correct.The keyword `on` used in the statement is the preferred way to attach an event. if you are talking about calling it in the `init` and not when the actual event is occurring you have to call the [`triggers`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#triggering-events)

Comment: I am not saying that event is not working. I am saying when this event is called in init and there we have to define which function is to be called. using on we are attaching an event with the trigger. But instead of this, I want to broadcast event and every model in my application should be aware of it. Then if some model wants to take action on that event then it can run the required function.

Answer (score 0):

Add to model in beforeSave

```
if ($this->isNewRecord) {
    $model->trigger(MyUser::EVENT_NEW_USER);
}
```

Comment: same thing here :D ,